# Reason and fix for "Error: Could not find or load main class Anne" on Scala Getting started tutorial

Tags: java, scala

I'm just starting out with Scala and have been following its Getting Started instructions. The second part of the instruction involves pulling the hello-world template by running the **sbt new scala/hello-world.g8** command.

My problem is that it keeps on giving me this error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Anne

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Anne**

I'd like to know the reason for this, as well as any possible fix I might use.
The following is my insight and attempts on fixing this problem.

Insight:
1. I might have a problem with java installation/scala/sbt installation that needs this class Anne since even with other sbt commands like **sbt sbtVersion** I get the same error

Attempts:

1. Change command to retrieve from full url:
**sbt new https://github.com/scala/hello-world.g8**

2.**(Edit):** *Previously I thought the repository scala/hello-world.g8 did not exist and tried getting from other repositories with no luck and with the same error as above. However it was pointed out below that the repository actually exists in this url* **https://github.com/scala/hello-world.g8**, thanks  Dmytro Mitin.

I was looking into the incorrect account (sbt) instead of (scala)

**(Edit): Day 2**

3. Uninstall/Reinstall sbt -- still getting the error

4. Checked if java running properly by compiling sample code and running ( successful )

Comment: What version you use of sbt (`sbt version`)?

Comment: Github repository is at https://github.com/scala/hello-world.g8 There's no `Anne` there.

Comment: pme - I downloaded the latest sbt msi version which is 1.2.8, I tried checking the version with command **sbt sbtVersion**, but I get the same error: <br> **Error: Could not find or load main class Anne<br>Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Anne**

Comment: Dmytro Mitin - Thanks, I'll edit my question and indicate that it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually running the command in Visual Studio Code's bash terminal. I tried running it with cmd and everything's now working fine.